Is is possible to read back the level of a output pin using libgpiod?
I am struggling to read back the value of a pin that I set before.
Is this even possible? (It is using sysfs!)
I have this code:
#include <gpiod.h> // gpiod_line_set_value, gpiod_line_get_value
#include <stdio.h>

// Open gpio device and read/write gpio pin

const char CHIP[] = "/dev/gpiochip1";
const int LINE = 3; // EN_FAN

// if arg 1 is 0/1, write to gpio pin else read from gpio pin

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   struct gpiod_chip* chip;
   struct gpiod_line* line;
   int val;

   chip = gpiod_chip_open(CHIP);
   if (!chip)
   {
      perror("Open chip failed");
      return 1;
   }

   line = gpiod_chip_get_line(chip, LINE);
   if (!line)
   {
      perror("Get line failed");
      gpiod_chip_close(chip);
      return 1;
   }

   if (argc == 2) // write
   {
      val = atoi(argv[1]);
      if (gpiod_line_request_output(line, "gpiot", val))
      {
         perror("Request line as output failed");
         gpiod_line_release(line);
         gpiod_chip_close(chip);
         return 1;
      }
      // No need to set. Default value in request_output is applied.
      val = gpiod_line_get_value(line);
      if (val == 0 || val == 1)
      {
         printf("Line value: %d\n", val);
      }
      else
      {
         perror("Get line value failed");
         gpiod_line_release(line);
         gpiod_chip_close(chip);
         return 1;
      }
   }
   else // read
   {
      if (gpiod_line_request_input(line, "gpiot"))
      {
         perror("Request line as input failed");
         gpiod_line_release(line);
         gpiod_chip_close(chip);
         return 1;
      }
      val = gpiod_line_get_value(line);
      if (val < 0)
      {
         perror("Get line value failed");
         gpiod_line_release(line);
         gpiod_chip_close(chip);
         return 1;
      }
      printf("Line value: %d\n", val);
   }

   gpiod_line_release(line);
   gpiod_chip_close(chip);

   return 0;
}

I have a gpiod_line_get_value() right after gpiod_line_request_output(). It always reads 0 regardless of what the pin is set to. (Setting the pin works, I can see the fan running).
Opening the pin in input mode (no argument to executable, gpiod_line_request_input) resets the pin. The fan no longer runs.
Additional question: Using gpiod_line_request_output instead of gpiod_line_request_output_flags used default flags (no bit set). This means it keeps the flags from before, right? The settings that were set from the kernel/device tree.

Why do you need it? What is the underlying problem that's supposed to solve? Why can't you keep a copy of the value in a variable?

It may depend on the GPIO controller and its driver.

If you need to check if the pin voltage really changed, connect the output to a separate input. Or maybe even better, use some hardware and an ADC input to measure the current through the fan.

Why do you need it? I really do not. The old interface i have to implement demands it. I could remove that feature but I would rather not. I cannot keep track if there are multiple threads and processes involved.

In many cases "output" configuration makes "input" return 0 or some rubbish. It is normal, so in good design you should be able to avoid reading pins that are output.
Even if it works in some cases, in fact, you will almost always read last set value even if you short pin to ground

The value returned by gpiod_line_get_value() on an output line depends on the device driver and underlying hardware.  It could be:

last value set
physical line value
something else

For push-pull lines (the default) it is typically the last value set, and that is usually the same as the physical line value.  But what is returned is up to the driver.
As you have discovered, requesting the line with gpiod_line_request_input() is not what you want if you want to read back the value of an output line - that will force the line back to an input.  You should request the line using gpiod_line_request() and request_type GPIOD_LINE_REQUEST_DIRECTION_AS_IS.
Btw, what happens when you release the line is also up to the driver - it may reset the line to its default configuration, and that may be an input.
And, in answer to your additional question, gpiod_line_request_output() clears all flags other than the output direction flag.  It does not leave the flags "from before".  It will clear any flags that were previously set.
Finally, a GPIO is not a reliable persistent store.  If you need to recall the value a line is set to then you should store that value in a persistent store as well as writing it to the GPIO.  Ideally you would have one process/thread responsible for controlling the line and the others would access the line value via that process/thread.
